# MySQL - Insert...Select with default value ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE doing full table scan

Tags: mysql

I have two table say table_first and table_second. I'm reading from a stream and upserting into table_first, while upserting fetching two columns from table_second and upsert query looks like below

```
insert into table_first(email, sku_id, product_id, country_code,
           event_name, event_time, price)
  select  'abc@gmail.com', pa.product_sku, '111', 'IN', 'test',
          '2022-11-18 03:51:18', pa.sale_price
    from  table_second pa
    where  pa.product_id = '111'
      and  country_code = 'IN'
ON DUPLICATE KEY  UPDATE
      event_name=VALUES(event_name),
      price=VALUES(price),
      product_id=VALUES(product_id);
```

This query running very slow and explain shows that its doing full table scan.

There is a non-unique index of product_id and country_code is present in table_second but

```
select  'abc@gmail.com', pa.product_sku, '111', 'IN', 'test',
        '2022-11-18 03:51:18', pa.sale_price
    from  table_second pa
    where  pa.product_id = '111'
      and  country_code = 'IN'
```

doing full table scan

while

```
select  pa.product_sku, pa.sale_price
    from  table_second pa
    where  pa.product_id = '111'
      and  country_code = 'IN'
```

making use of index.

Create Statements

---

table_first

---

```
CREATE TABLE `table_first` (
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `country_code` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `sku_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `event_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`email`,`country_code`,`sku_id`,`event_time`),
  KEY `delete_index` (`country_code`,`email`,`product_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

---

table_second

---

```
CREATE TABLE `table_second` (
  `product_sku` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `country_code` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sale_price` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,  
  `update_ts` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_sku`,`country_code`),
  KEY `ix_update_ts` (`update_ts`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `ix_product_id_country` (`product_id`,`country_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Any suggestions would be of great help. Thank you.

Comment: can pls add the create table for both tables

Comment: @BerndBuffen, added create statements in description

Comment: Actually ,its not doing full table scan. MySQL Workbench misleads me. when I executed above query in new tab of workbench, it shows that its using index. Thanks for looking into this

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something, the upsert is irrelevant to the question.  You have two similar `SELECTs` both fetching from the same `table2`, but with unexplained performance differences.  Is that correct?  If so, please remove all mention of the upsert.

This begs for an index containing those two columns, which you do have:

```
where  pa.product_id = '111'
  and  country_code = 'IN'
```